# How to assign one variable per word of a string

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, gawk

How would you suggest to consecutively assign one variable per word of string?

I am looking for the short command: one-liner and without loop if possible. It should have of the form

```
echo "<sring>"  | your_command
```

**Example**:

- The string is "word1 word2 word3"
- I want to assign the variable `w1` to `word1`, `w2` to `word2` and `w3` to `word3`.

Comment: after storing into variable, what kind of operation you are going to do with that  ? so.. we can advise more flexible solution

Comment: Variables would be assigned and used in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in `ksh93` but not in `bash` since `bash` runs the `read` in a sub-shell:

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | read w1 w2 w3
printf '"%s"\n' "$w1" "$w2" "$w3"
```

This means that you simply *can't* have an assignment as part of a pipeline in `bash`.

The workaround is to use the variables before the pipeline sub-shell exits:

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | { read w1 w2 w3 && printf '"%s"\n' "$w1" "$w2" "$w3"; }
```

or,

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | {
  read w1 w2 w3
  printf '"%s"\n' "$w1" "$w2" "$w3"
}
```

This works in both shells:

```
read w1 w2 w3 <<<"word1 word2 word3"
printf '"%s"\n' "$w1" "$w2" "$w3"
```